# Where should I save Photo in web application like Photo Blog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Where should I save Photo in web application like Photo blog?
I mean should I use physical path or database. I planned to use ASP.NET MVC and MSSQL.
If you have any idea, please suggest to me. and any sample db design or app links can provide to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of opinion, but I personally think it makes much more sense to store a photo as a file, and just store the path in the database, than to store BLOBs. I haven't explored the performance penalties if any.

In fact, I haven't ever found the need to use a database for a photoblog. Files for the photos and any associated annotations have worked well enough. I suppose for a really heavily-trafficked site that would not be sufficient.

Comment: well... very good answer. I will try to save physical path. actually i want to use database for blog post, comments, etc...

Comment: Agreed. Chuck the files either on an internal CDN, or an external one (e.g S3). Then use convention to get the files (e.g the ID of the Photo can be the filename, or if you want clean file names, use slugs)

Answer (score 1):

If the images are not of huge size you can try the Filestream option in sql server 2008.

Comment: thanks for your feedback : one photo for round about 7 mb or 9 mb